# C# Dissasembly - Find variable name from memory address

Tags: c#, assembly, x86-64

I'm debugging some C# code in the Visual Studio (2017) Disassembly and I wanna know if I can find variable name by the a physical address.

I have some variable in my program at the location of the base pointer+30h address:

```
00007FFEEB4B19DB  mov         dword ptr [rbp+30h],eax  
00007FFEEB4B19DE  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rbp+30h]
```

and I can't figure out which variable is it, just for the argument, by debugging it was relativity easy to find which variable is linked to (rbp+64h) address, and others too.

there is a way to find the map? or a way to do that with the debugger? 
I already looked at some posts and couldn't find an answer that work for me.

Thank a lot,

Or

Comment: variables don't have names though. are you looking for a function argument?

Comment: I mean that if ill execute:
 mov         dword ptr [rbp+64h],ecx
 the rbp+64h address which is 00007FFEEB47DAC4
its an int that I named it num at my code

Comment: can you share the c# code?

Comment: That's actually happen in my foreach loop:
    foreach (int num in nums)
    {

    }

Comment: VS should be able to add C# annotations over assembly commands. Apart from that you can try to temporarily apply some unique commands to your variables say add some specific (per variable) constant (like a += 1; b+=2, etc) and you'll see in the assembly code what address corresponds to what variable by inspecting `add` instructions.